# Mouse hover detection over specific game object in unity

Tags: unity

I'm new in unity and trying to interact with unity ecosystem.
What I'm facing is attaching a script to GameObject(Child of root canvas).

Script is for listening mouse hover over the gameObject it attached to, but
listening whole canvas hovering, What i'm doing wrong i don't know.

**Problem**:
Hover listening over whole canvas

**Expected**:It should listen only over gameObject to which script attached to.

I've added Box collider 2d object and bounded it correctly.

**HoverDetector Script Attached to GameObject:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoverDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hovered Over" + gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For Canvas/ UI elements, use the `OnPointerEnter` from the `IPointerEnterHandler` interface

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/how-can-i-detect-that-the-mouse-is-over-a-button-so-that-i-can-display-some-ui-t/163322#163322

Comment: `OnMouseOver` works for objects with individual collider components in the game's 3D world. Objects in UI (anything under a `Canvas`) need to use the methods explained in the Q&A Zibelas has linked. If you have any difficulty implementing the linked solutions, you can **edit your question** to show how you tried applying them and what went wrong, so we can re-open the question for answers targeted at solving that specific problem.